# Active message count in Azure service bus keep decrease after kill the app

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am using ServiceBusProcessorClient consume the events from topic:

```
ServiceBusProcessorClient serviceBusProcessorClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(busConnectionString)
                .processor()
                .disableAutoComplete()
                .topicName(topicName)
                .subscriptionName(subscriptionName)
                .processMessage(processMessage)
                .processError(context -> processError(context,countdownLatch))
                .maxConcurrentCalls(maxConcurrentCalls)
                .buildProcessorClient();

serviceBusProcessorClient.start();
```

But after kill the app ,The message count in Azure service bus keep decrease until reach 0 .
I can not understand what goes wrong in my implementation.
The Topic configuration :
[topic config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwFbi.png)

The subscription configuration :
[subscription config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E3Ua.png)

Comment: Did you configure a different Time-to-Live other than the default on the Messages itself or the topic/queue?

Comment: Hi @Tobi ,
Thanks for your response , I have update the question with the configuration of the topic and the subscription . 
I have 4 hour TTL but the event count become 0 in few minutes .

Comment: what do you mean by kill the app ?

Comment: I am working with aks , uninstall by helm .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like helm deletes using the [background propagation policy](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/3974136b6eba92f17a821aac52a80b59a9fa1202/pkg/kube/client.go#L430) which lets the garbage collector to delete in the background. This is probably why your service is processing messages even after you run uninstall.

You would have to kill the process directly in addition to helm uninstall to not have anymore messages from being processed.